# Implementing Dueling DQN on TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I'm trying to implement my own Dueling DQN using tensorflow 2 based on https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06581.pdf. I'm actually training it on the Atlantis environment but I can't get good results ([Mean reward per game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4toH.png) keeps decreasing while [TD loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDoK2.png) increases). Though I believe I got the logic from the paper, I don't know if it comes from the direct implementation of the network or the chosen parameters.

EDIT : Using tf.keras.utils.plot_model gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMCvH.png).

```
class DQNAgent:
  def __init__(self, state_shape, n_actions, epsilon=0):
    self.state_input = Input(shape=state_shape, name='State')
    self.x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides=2, activation='relu')(self.state_input)
    self.x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=2, activation='relu')(self.x)
    self.x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=2, activation='relu')(self.x)
    self.x = Flatten()(self.x)
    self.x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(self.x)

    self.head_v = Dense(256,activation='relu')(self.x)
    self.head_v = Dense(1, activation='linear',name="Value")(self.head_v)
    self.head_v = RepeatVector(n_actions)(self.head_v)
    self.head_v = Flatten()(self.head_v)

    self.head_a = Dense(256,activation='relu')(self.x)
    self.head_a = Dense(n_actions, activation='linear',name='Activation')(self.head_a)

    self.m_head_a = RepeatVector(n_actions)(tf.keras.backend.mean(self.head_a,axis=1,keepdims=True))
    self.m_head_a = Flatten(name='meanActivation')(self.m_head_a)

    self.head_a = Subtract()([self.head_a,self.m_head_a])

    self.head_q = Add(name = "Q-value")([self.head_v,self.head_a])


    self.network = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[self.state_input], outputs=[self.head_q])
    self.weights = self.network.trainable_variables
    self.epsilon = epsilon
    self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3)

  def get_qvalues(self, state_t):
    return self.network(state_t)

  def train(self, exp_replay, batch_size=64):
    states, actions, rewards, next_states, is_done = exp_replay.sample(batch_size)
    is_not_done = 1 - is_done

    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
      current_qvalues = agent.get_qvalues(states)
      current_action_qvalues = tf.reduce_sum(tf.one_hot(actions, n_actions) * current_qvalues, axis=-1)
      next_qvalues_target = target_network.get_qvalues(next_states)
      next_state_values_target = tf.reduce_max(next_qvalues_target, axis=-1)
      reference_qvalues = rewards + gamma*next_state_values_target*is_not_done
      td_loss = (current_action_qvalues - reference_qvalues)**2
      td_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(td_loss)

    var_list = agent.weights
    grads = t.gradient(td_loss,var_list)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, var_list))
    return td_loss


  def sample_actions(self, qvalues):
    batch_size, n_actions = qvalues.shape
    random_actions = np.random.choice(n_actions, size=batch_size)
    best_actions = tf.math.argmax(qvalues, axis=-1)
    should_explore = np.random.choice([0, 1], batch_size, p = [1-self.epsilon, self.epsilon])
    return np.where(should_explore, random_actions, best_actions)


def load_weights_into_target_network(agent, target_network):
  for t, e in zip(target_network.network.trainable_variables, agent.network.trainable_variables):
    t.assign(e)

env = make_env() # Apply frame buffer on "AtlantisDeterministic-V4" env
env.reset()
n_actions = env.action_space.n
state_dim = env.observation_space.shape

agent = DQNAgent(state_dim, n_actions, epsilon=0.5)    
target_network = DQNAgent(state_dim, n_actions)

exp_replay = ReplayBuffer(10**5) # Random experience replay buffer
play_and_record(agent, env, exp_replay, n_steps=10000) # Plays exactly n_steps and records each transition in the ReplayBuffer
gamma = 0.99

for i in trange(10**5):
  play_and_record(agent, env, exp_replay, 10)

  td_loss = agent.train(exp_replay, 64)

  # adjust agent parameters
  if i % 500 == 0:
    load_weights_into_target_network(agent, target_network)
    agent.epsilon = max(agent.epsilon * 0.99, 0.01)
```

Comment: Could you check if the neural net is being created correctly? I don't recognize the way you are building it. Normally using the Keras API it would be model.add() etc etc. Rather than self.x = something.

Comment: I added the model plot through edit. I builded the network using what I found on this page  : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you prepopulate your buffer with 10k steps in play_and_record. Then perform for 10 * 10**5 steps with a training step every 10 actions on to your neural net? I am a little concerned about the experience replay. Perhaps try populating with 64 random states first. Before running the training. Also playing with the buffer size and the batch size may improve your results. Lots of things to tune and I would use a fully random agent to prepopulate rather than with epsilon 0.5. Also I would perform sanity checks that the correct action is being passed.

Comment: Yeah you're right, that's how it is designed. I'll try your proposal and give some feedbacks. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from the target network not updating correctly, basic programming mistake. Yet, it worked really well with the given buffer modification. Thanks for your help.